# Синкретические члены предложения

Tags: синтаксис, методика

Вопрос учителям нашего форума.

В предложении "Варенье из смородины" двоякая квалификация - несогласованное определение и дополнение.

Но ученик подчеркнул как дополнение, за что ему снизили оценку.

А как поступаете вы? Следует ли за это снижать оценку, может, надо указать два члена предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несогласованные определения действительно совмещают значения определения  и значения дополнения или обстоятельства. Снизили оценку верно, потому что ученик не увидел **превалирующей** синтаксической функции слова. Варенье какое? из чего? - определение с оттенком дополнения. Если бы он увидел только  функцию определения, ошибки бы не было. Идеально, конечно, двойное подчёркивание, но уж если одинарное, то следовало выделить главную функцию.

Вот в предложении Климат в Ленинграде сырой "в Ленинграде" тоже имеет две функции - обстоятельства и определения, но если бы мы обозначили его функцию только как определение, Вы бы снизили оценку? Ведь явно же вопрос сначала нужно поставить от сказуемого - сырой где? в Ленинграде, а только потом от подлежащего - климат какой?. Это всего лишь оттенок. Кто увидел - молодец, не увидел - бог с ним, главное-то увидел.

Так что я согласна с учителем,несогласованное определение нужно учить видеть, не увидел - ошибка.

Comment: А вы  школе объясняете синкретические члены предложения? Дело в том, что учительница снизила оценку потому что ученик подчеркнул как дополнение, она зачеркнула и подчеркнула как определение.

Comment: Людмила, что-то я не понял... С вареньем еще ладно, хотя как можно требовать от учеников однозначного знания того, что здесь определение, а не дополнение, если критерии размыты?! Но климат-то? Мало того, что начал бы вопросы ставить я именно от климата, так еще и вопрос был бы "где?", "в каком месте?". И это мне очевидно, говорить о климате бессмысленно, не назвав географическую точку. А "сырой в Ленинграде" - это вообще за пределами моего понимания. Сферический конь в вакууме.

Comment: Хоть вопрос отдельный открывай... Вы не ошиблись с формулировками? Вопрос вы предлагаете ставить именно ***от "сырой" к "в Ленинграде"?***

Comment: Обстоятельство  всегда относится к сказуемому, чаще к глаголу или его формам.Здесь сказуемое составное именное - есть сырой,(был сырой) но связка "есть" нулевая, значит, ставим вопрос от "сырой". "Климат где?" неверно, надо "где есть климат? где существует климат?" Обстоятельство - это те обстоятельства, при которых совершается действие.

Comment: В школе просто не произносится термин "синкретический", там говорится, что члены предложения могут быть однозначными и многозначными. Московский поезд прибыл без опоздания - "московский"-однозначный член предложения - определение. Поезд (какой?куда идущий?) на Москву прибыл без опоздания -определение и обстоятельство , но от обстоятельства только оттенок, а вот Поезд идёт на Москву - вот здесь только куда? - обстоятельство.

Comment: Климат в Ленинграде /сырой. Ленинградский климат /сырой. Климат в Ленинграде всегда был сырым. Составное именное сказуемое, есть группа подлежащего и есть группа сказуемого (обычно при отсутствии связки и именной части, выраженной сущ. , между этими группами ставится тире). Климат в Ленинграде - группа подлежащего, В Ленинграде - обстоятельственное несогласованное определение, при чем тут вопрос от сказуемого? Поэтому "сырой в Ленинграде" - это за гранью моего понимания тоже.

Comment: @ Sibylla,т. е. вы отрицаете дуплексив?